# Strange effect in Android AlertDialog, gray stripe

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

[image: Alert dialog on 2.3.3]

On Android 4 this works fine but on 2.3.3 I'm getting (instead of a total dark gray background) a light grey horizontal stripe behind the top of the OK button. Any ideas what might be causing this? Thanks!

```
private void showResult(final String message) {
   final Context context = this;

    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            builder.setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
            });
            builder.create().show();
        }
    };

    this.runOnUiThread(run);
}
```

I have:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

and in values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Screenshot added to Q. Thanks

Comment: How does that look in the emulator for 2.3.3?  That screenshot looks like a manufacturer-custom theme, so YMMV on other devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether you're looking for a dark gray background on everything, or just for consistency.

Have you tried changing the Theme of the [`AlertDialog.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder(android.content.Context,%20int))?  In API11+, there's a second constructor you can use which takes an integer argument to set the theme.  Perhaps setting it back to the "traditional" theme would get it to look the same across versions?

> `public AlertDialog.Builder (Context context, int theme)`
>
> Since: API Level 11
>
> Constructor using a context and theme for this builder and the AlertDialog it creates. The actual theme that an AlertDialog uses is a private implementation, however you can here supply either the name of an attribute in the theme from which to get the dialog's style (such as alertDialogTheme or one of the constants `AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL`, `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK`, or `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`.

If that doesn't work for you, you can use `AlertDialog.Builder().setView(View)` to be able to further specify the attributes of each of the items in the dialog (so you could potentially put `Button`s in the `View` you pass, and set the background of the buttons to gray).

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a good answer but I'm using minsdk 7. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: You can use newer API calls in older API code, so long as the code path taken in the older API doesn't use them.  In other words, `if(device SDK version >= 11) { /* use new method to pass old theme */ } else { /* use old method */ } `.  That might buy you some consistency, at least.  Or use `setView` which is in API1.